# CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded:https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/1/d/4/CocoaAsyncSocket/7.6.1/CocoaAsyncSocket.podspec.json

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, ui-automation, xcuitest, pod-install

I tried `pod install` command and am getting this error.

```
% pod install
Analyzing dependencies
[!] CDN: trunk Repo update failed - 18 error(s):
CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: 

    https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/1/d/4/CocoaAsyncSocket/0.0.1/CocoaAsyncSocket.podspec.json Response: 302 <html>
    <head><title>302 Found</title></head>
    <body bgcolor="white">
    <center><h1>302 Moved Temporarily</h1></center>
    <hr><center>Umbrella Cloud Security Gateway</center>
    </body>
    </html>
    
    CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/1/d/4/CocoaAsyncSocket/7.0.3/CocoaAsyncSocket.podspec.json Response: 302 <html>
    <head><title>302 Found</title></head>
    <body bgcolor="white">
    <center><h1>302 Moved Temporarily</h1></center>
    <hr><center>Umbrella Cloud Security Gateway</center>
    </body>
    </html>
    
    CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/1/d/4/CocoaAsyncSocket/7.2.2/CocoaAsyncSocket.podspec.json Response: 302 <html>
    <head><title>302 Found</title></head>
    <body bgcolor="white">
    <center><h1>302 Moved Temporarily</h1></center>
    <hr><center>Umbrella Cloud Security Gateway</center>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I tried everything but still getting this error.

Comment: Did you ever figure this issue out? Currently running into the exact same error and cannot find an answer

Comment: Hi, I resolved this issue. I keep the Xcode in the 'downloads' folder instead of 'Applications'. Once I move to Applications I never see this issue again.

Comment: Hmm my xcode is already in the applications folder, there wasn't anything else you did that could have resolved it?

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else having this exact error. After some back and forth with our Security team they were able to 'resolve' this issue by whitelisting the cdn.jsdelivr.net domain.

The issue stemmed from our Cloud security software (Cisco Umbrella) causing a 302 code to be returned when Cocoapods was trying to access that domain. Cocoapods (v1.10.1 as of the time of this response) does not handle a 302 code and throws the error you see in the original post.

You can see the Cocoapods Ruby code throwing the error here: https://github.com/CocoaPods/Core/blob/1.10.1/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb#L372-L417